# ERROR : org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain not found

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I'm trying to execute a simple pig script through oozie workflow which imports a python jar and as well as some other jar and eventually getting error like:

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exception invoking main(), java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain not found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1895)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1801)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1893)
... 9 more

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
```

and for this workflow i added all jars in **lib** directory including **pig.jar** .

Answer (score 3):

Please check the Pig Jar should be present in Physical location of the Node where the Oozie Workflow is running.

Also You can plase the Pig jar in hadoop location of Oozie Shared Lib, and pass parameter

> oozie.use.system.libpath        =   true

these will read the jar from Shared Lib Location

Comment: I using CDH 5.x , and Cloudera Manager , how do I make sure that this jar file is at the right location  ? What is the jar name and where does it need to be ? Thx.